# joomla:How to fix "CLASS 'JPLATFORMUTILITY' NOT FOUND"

Tags: joomla

I am newbie to Joomla and get this error when I open main page in my website.

```
CLASS 'JPLATFORMUTILITY' NOT FOUND
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: have you recently upgraded the PHP version?

Comment: No, I did not anything except inserting few articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out storage space in your server.
I had the same problem, and it turned out that the storage space was full in the server.